# What is the :hover active area? the box generated by element or based on html structure

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

```css
nav {
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  > nav {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    a {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
.main:hover > .sub {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main">
  <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
  <nav class="sub">
    <a href="#">Menu 2-1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu 2-2</a>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

As we can see from the code snippets above, nav.sub is an absolute element and not included by nav.main's box model, but when I move the cursor above nav.sub, nav.sub shows up.

So I am just curious what is the :hover active area? the box generated by element or based on HTML structure. I cannot find reference or spec :(

Comment: Hovering an element also triggers the hover state on any ancestors, based on DOM structure. Whether those elements are _visually_ “connected” or not, does not matter in this regard.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't actually demonstrate anything. Your stylesheet is in a preprocessor language, not vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[Selectors itself doesn't define this.](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) Some host languages may do so. HTML does. From [W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/matching-html-elements-using-selectors.html#selectordef-hover) and [WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-hover) (emphasis mine):

> The `:hover` pseudo-class is defined to match an element "while the user *designates* an element with a pointing device". For the purposes of defining the `:hover` pseudo-class only, an HTML user agent must consider an element as being one that the user *designates* if it is:
>
> - An element that the user indicates using a pointing device.
> - **An element that has a descendant that the user indicates using a pointing device.**
> - An element that is the labeled control of a `label` element that is currently matching `:hover`.

This means, in terms of selectors, that any HTML element that matches `:has(:hover)` also matches `:hover`. This is true regardless of how the ancestor and its `:hover` descendant are actually laid out.

In your example, designating either `.main` or `.sub` will cause `.main` to match `:hover`, thereby causing `.sub` to match the complex selector `.main:hover > .sub`.

Answer (score -1):

It is working based on css property. Here opacity value is 1. Previously it was 0. If opacity 0 means element is available there but we cannot see. Please do google it for opacity.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main{
  background: gray;
 }
 .sub{
  display: none;
 }
 .main:hover > .sub{
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
 <nav class="main">
  <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
  <nav class="sub">
    <a href="#">Menu 2-1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu 2-2</a>
  </nav>
</nav>
```